# How to make a Keyboard extension's name shorter (via info.plist keys)

Tags: ios, xcode, info-plist, ios-keyboard-extension

I am developing a Keyboard Extension for iOS 8.

Everything is ok but when I run on device, the name of the Keyboard is "myBoard - mBoard". I would like it to just be "myBoard".

**My extension info.plist is:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-    1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Meboard</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>tapi.Meboard.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>XPC!</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
<string></string>
<key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
<false/>
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>IsASCIICapable</key>
        <false/>
        <key>PrefersRightToLeft</key>
        <false/>
        <key>RequestsOpenAccess</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.keyboard-service</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}.myBoard</string>
</dict>
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: If you remove the app Name then how the user will know that this keyboard is a extension of which app. I think, if you do this then Apple might reject your app due to security purpose.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this isn't consistently possible as of iOS 8.1. We've experimented with numerous combinations of display keys and while it seems that you can in some case simply appear as "myBoard" or whatever your keyboard name is, it seems impossible to appear as simply "myBoard" and not "myBoard - myBoard" (or something similar) in all cases.

The set up we ended up with is as follows:

`CFBundleName`: identical on both container app and keyboard extension
`CFBundleDisplayName`: only present for the keyboard extension
`CFBundleExecutable`: the same as `CFBundleDisplayName` on the Keyboard extension, the normal `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}` for the container app.

This is the best we've found. I'll update if I figure out anything better.

Comment: Tested and it is correct, I'm using Bundle name: ${PRODUCT_NAME} for both App and App Extension. For Bundle display name, use identical name (eg: "myApp") for both.

Answer (score 1):

In your Contaning app, set the Bundle Display Name empty and in your Keyboard Extension set the Bundle Display Name "MyBoard".

After making this changes, it will show "MyBoard -"

Comment: Thanks for your fast response but it still have character "-" behind the MyBoard :-(.

Answer (score 1):

To have what you want you should set the display name EXACTLY the same in both info.plist files (app and extension).